# apt: Debian repository does not have a Release file

Tags: bash, raspberry-pi, command-line-interface, repository, apt

Ok, so I just turned on my Pi4 and did my usual `apt update`, but I got a strange output:

```
$ sudo apt update

[etc, no errors above this...]                     
Err:9 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye-security Release                   
  404  Not Found [IP: 151.101.62.132 80]
Hit:10 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/theofficialgman/flatpak-no-bwrap/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:4 https://box64.debian.ryanfortner.dev/debian ./ InRelease                 
Hit:7 https://box86.debian.ryanfortner.dev/debian ./ InRelease                 
Reading package lists... Done                                   
E: The repository 'http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye-security Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

I am a bit confused by this. I am a noob, but I know a bit about bash/apt. I have come across this error before, but only when I tried to add a custom repository, not with an official one. Last time, I fixed this error by deleting that source from `sources.list.d` but I don's know whether I should because it looks like a vital source. It used to work fine until this morning.
Just in case it matters, here are my system specs:

Board: Raspberry Pi 4 Model B 8GB RAM
OS: Debian 11 Bullseye
(if you need any more say in the comments)

Any help appreciated!

Comment: This question is [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here, but it will fit on [Unix.SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score -2, accepted):

cd /etc/apt/source.list.d

sudo rm filename.list

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: The question is about the `bullseye-security` entry, which is configured in `/etc/apt/sources.list`, *not* in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say your `/etc/apt/sources.list` has an incorrect entry.

You can see [this link](https://wiki.debian.org/SourcesList) and edit your `sources.list` by replacing the line

```
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye-security (...)
```

with

```
deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security bullseye-security (...)
```

Replace `(...)` with `main contrib non-free` as needed.

By the way, this question would probably be more legitimate on [unix.stackexchange.com](https://unix.stackexchange.com)

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks! Though now I am even more confused: https://pastebin.com/ff6Jx1DH

Comment: Here is my full /etc/apt/sources.list: https://pastebin.com/x0xdWuDQ

Comment: Those are different errors from the one you mentioned in your post.

Comment: The gnome3 PPA has reached EOL, see [launchpad.net/~gnome3-team/+archive/ubuntu/gnome3](https://launchpad.net/~gnome3-team/+archive/ubuntu/gnome3).  You can purge it from your system (just find the relevant file in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` and remove it.

Comment: Same for [gnome3-staging](https://launchpad.net/~gnome3-team/+archive/ubuntu/gnome3-staging).

Comment: Thanks! Pi-apps installed weird stuff and didn't remove stale dependencies, but now fixed!